# Scrolling animation for section on Website.

Tags: css, scrollview, css-animations

I’m working on my portfolio website and I was wondering how do I make a block of text appeared when I scrolled down the website?  So when someone scroll down, say example my About me section to appear on the left.

Comment: This question is something that could be answered by googling it. This site isn't for us to do your research for you

Comment: Sorry Jessica, You will have to provide some code to show what you are trying to accomplish and that you're at least attempting it on your own first. I can tell you that it is a mix of js and css however this answer is just as general as your question. This is a helpful article for new stackoverflow users: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of text effecton mouse scroll you are looking for. Here’s a nice little timeline I once used. You can change this to represent what you like:

HTML

```
  <div class="stem-wrapper">
    <div class="stem"></div>
    <div class="stem-background"></div>
</div>

<header class="section header">
    <div class="section-inner">

        <div class="master-head">
            <h1 class="page-title">Colored Stem</h1>
            <p class="page-description">Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear. Your cells react to bacteria and viruses differently than mine. You don't get sick, I do. That's also clear. But for some reason, you and I react the exact same way to water.</p>
            <p class="scroll-button" onClick="$('.post-wrapper .post:first-child .stem-overlay .icon').click();">Ready to go for a ride?</p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- section-inner -->
</header> <!-- header -->
```

CSS

```
/*==========  Global  ==========*/
/*==========  Basics  ==========*/
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #112C30;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #B9CFD0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
a {
  color: #B9CFD0;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B9CFD0;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}
/*==========  Sections  ==========*/
.header {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6fc7d4 0%, #39ACBD 100%);
}
.header .master-head {
  padding: 7% 30px;
}
.header .page-title {
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.header .page-description {
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
}
.header .scroll-button {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #3093A2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.header .scroll-button:hover {
  background: #246f7b;
}
.header .scroll-button:active {
  background: #194c53;
}
.main-content {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.main-content .section-inner,
.main-content .post-wrapper {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.main-content .section-inner:before,
.main-content .post-wrapper:before,
.main-content .section-inner:after,
.main-content .post-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.main-content .section-inner:after,
.main-content .post-wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}
.footer {
  background: #112C30;
  padding: 150px 0px 300px 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.footer .good-bye {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
.footer .good-bye p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  clear: both;
}
.section .section-inner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1024px;
}
@media only screen {
  .section .section-inner {
width: auto;
max-width: 1024px;
  }
}
/*==========  Stem  ==========*/
.stem-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
}
.stem-wrapper.color-yellow .stem-background {
  background: #E9E566;
}
.stem-wrapper.color-green .stem-background {
  background: #35C189;
}
.stem-wrapper.color-white .stem-background {
  background: #FFF;
}
.stem-wrapper .stem,
.stem-wrapper .stem-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -30px;
  width: 60px;
}
.stem-wrapper .stem {
  background: #1e4f56;
  height: 100%;
}
.stem-wrapper .stem-background {
  background: #39ACBD;
  height: 50%;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.stem-padding,
.single-stem-icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: transparent url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/22043/stem-mask.png) repeat-y top center;
}
.single-stem-icon.scroll-to-top {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/22043/scroll-to-top-icon.png);
}
/*==========  Post wrapper ==========*/
.post-wrapper {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.post-wrapper:before,
.post-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.post-wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}
.post-wrapper .post {
  position: relative;
  width: 432px;
  padding: 0px 0px 60px 0px;
  clear: both;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.post-wrapper .post.hidden .post-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px) rotateX(30deg);
  transform: translateY(100px) rotateX(30deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
.post-wrapper .post:hover .post-content,
.post-wrapper .post.active .post-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
.post-wrapper .post:hover .post-content .meta,
.post-wrapper .post.active .post-content .meta {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
.post-wrapper .post:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
.post-wrapper .post:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}
.post-wrapper .post:nth-child(even) .stem-overlay {
  left: -110px;
}
.post-wrapper .post:nth-child(odd) .stem-overlay {
  right: -110px;
}
.post-wrapper .post.music-icon .stem-overlay .icon {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/22043/music-icon.png);
}
.post-wrapper .post.bitbucket-icon .stem-overlay .icon {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/22043/bitbucket-icon.png);
}
.post-wrapper .post.m-icon .stem-overlay .icon {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/22043/m-icon.png);
}
.post-wrapper .post.twitter-icon .stem-overlay .icon {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/22043/twitter-icon.png);
}
.post-wrapper .post .stem-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 60px;
}
.post-wrapper .post .stem-overlay .icon {
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.post-wrapper .post .stem-overlay .stem-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: transparent url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/22043/stem-mask.png) repeat-y top center;
}
.post-wrapper .post .post-content {
  opacity: .3;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
.post-wrapper .post .post-content .meta {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.post-wrapper .post .post-content .post-title {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
/*==========  Media queries  ==========*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
  .main-content,
  .main-content .section-inner {
max-width: none;
  }
  .stem-wrapper {
left: 80px;
  }
  .stem-padding,
  .single-stem-icon {
margin: 0px;
float: left;
margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .post-wrapper .post,
  .post-wrapper .post:nth-child(even),
  .post-wrapper .post:nth-child(odd) {
width: auto;
margin-left: 110px;
float: none;
  }
  .post-wrapper .post .stem-overlay,
  .post-wrapper .post:nth-child(even) .stem-overlay,
  .post-wrapper .post:nth-child(odd) .stem-overlay {
left: -60px;
right: auto;
  }
  .post-wrapper .post .post-content {
padding: 0px 50px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .header .page-title {
font-size: 40px;
  }
  .post-wrapper .post {
margin-left: 90px !important;
  }
  .post-wrapper .post .post-content {
padding: 0 25px;
  }
  .stem-wrapper {
left: 60px;
  }
  .stem-padding,
  .single-stem-icon {
margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

JavaScript

```
($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setupFade();
        setupClickToScroll();
        setupPostAnimation();
        setupScrollToTop();
     enableScrollAbortion();

        // Trigger window.scroll, this will initiate some of the scripts
        $(window).scroll();
  });


  // Allow user to cancel scroll animation by manually scrolling
  function enableScrollAbortion() {
    var $viewport = $('html, body');
    $viewport.on('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e) {
        if ( e.which > 0 || e.type === 'mousedown' || e.type === 'mousewheel') {
             $viewport.stop();
        }
```